# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code

This error occurred in vscode while trying to run a flutter app. I generated/created a new flutter project from terminal and attempted to run it, but the error won't stop showing. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. I ran the same apps on Intellij and they worked fine. I'm getting this error only on VSCode. Answers on other questions similar to this suggests fixes on Android studio, but VSCode != Android studio

Answer (score 3):

This error is a Gradle build error resulting from an incompatibility bug between Gradle 5.*.* and Jdk 9. If your JAVA_HOME environment variable points to a jdk version 9, just change it to java 8 or jdk 11, i.e., set your JAVA_HOME variable to point to a java 8 installation.